Как правильно: будет или будете в предложении
Как правильно:
Зато не только ты, но и моя сестренка будет счастлива.
Или
Зато не только ты, но и моя сестренка будете счастливы.
???

Правильно:
Зато не только ты, но и моя сестренка будет счастлива.
Пояснение

При наличии однородных подлежащих согласование со сказуемым возможно как во мн. числе (по смыслу), так и в ед. числе (по форме). Согласование по форме делается для того, чтобы рядом стоящие слова не конфликтовали между собой.

В данном случае выбор ед.числа можно сделать по слуху: Зато не только ты (будешь счастлив), но и моя сестренка будет счастлива.

Тема регулируется правилом Розенталя §190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими.


В общем случае учитывается действие разных факторов, но здесь есть готовое решение для сопоставительного союза НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И:
Если между однородными подлежащими стоят сопоставительные 
союзы, то в зависимости от их типа возможна двоякая форма 
согласования:
1) при союзе как... так и (близком по значению к 
повторяющемуся союзу и... и) сказуемое ставится в форме 
множественного числа, например: Как наука, так и искусство в 
своем развитии отражают развитие общества;

2) при союзах не только... но и, не столько... сколько и др. 
(содержащих оттенок противопоставления) сказуемое обычно 
согласуется с ближайшим из однородных подлежащих, например:
В окружающей нас действительности не только большое, но и 
малое должно интересовать наблюдательного писателя.

